# Pandas to_datetime loses timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My raw data has a column with timestamps in ISO8601 format like this:

> '2017-07-25T06:00:02+02:00'

Since the data is in CSV format, it will be read as object/string. Therefore I'm converting it to datetime like this.

```
import pandas pd
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=False)

#df['time'][0]
df['time'][0].isoformat()
```

Unfortunately this results in UTC timestamps and the timezone is lost. For instance **df['time'][0].tzinfo** is not set.

> Timestamp('2017-07-25 04:00:02')
>
> '2017-07-25T04:00:02'

I'm looking for a way to keep the timezone info in each of the timezone objects. But without re-setting it to CEST (Central European Summer Time) afterwards since this information is already included in the ISO8601 timezone offset in the raw-data. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here's how I solved it.

There's a great article about [Timezones and Python](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2015/python-and-timezones), which helped me to come to a solution. It relies on the [ISO8601 Python packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601).

```
import iso8601

times = ['2017-07-25 06:00:02+02:00',
         '2017-07-25 08:15:08+02:00',
         '2017-07-25 12:08:00+02:00',
         '2017-07-25 13:10:12+02:00',
         '2017-07-25 15:11:55+02:00',
         '2017-07-25 16:00:00+02:00'
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(iso8601.parse_date)
df['time'][0]
```

Which produces the following output and keeps the timezone information.

> Timestamp('2017-07-25 06:00:02+0200', tz='+02:00')